# custom drupal 6 is not showing on the page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-blocks

I recently started working for this company and I am trying to modify the php code that was already created to display blocks on a page. I am using my localhost and wamp to test and develop my code. the first block that I created worked as the only thing that I did was to copy and modify the title of the code but now that I am trying to do the same for second and for some reason is not working. on my drupal 6 localhost block page I could see the block that I created and the region assign to it but is still not visible in the page. What am I missing?

Below is the code that I am using. Any help will be appreciated.

on the Page specific visibility settings this is the php code :

```
<p><?php return _admin_block_visibility('breeding_race_results'); ?></p>


$blocks['race_results'] = array('info' => t('Race Results'),
    'status' => 1,
    'region' => 'middle',
    'visibility' => 2,
    'weight' => -100,
    'pages' => '<?php return _admin_block_visibility(\'race_results\'); ?>',
        );
case 'race_results':
    $block['subject'] = t('Race Results');
    $block['content'] = admin_race_results_block_content();
    break;
```

Comment: As it is now, your question is too difficult to understand. Please clarify the question if you wish to get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in Drupal, you don't need to write a code to have things displayed. Use Drupal core blocks management (Structure > Blocks) or use [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module to tell the system where you want certain elements like blocks to appear (what page or what type of pages etc.). Also, use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create a dynamic lists of things to be displayed anywhere in the system.

Also, if a block is not showing where it suppose to, add there some text text and check if that will work. You will want to figure out first if the problem is with the code in the block (that makes the results invisible) or the problem is that the block is not rendering at all.